# Something like __pycache__ for Python 2.x?

Tags: python, python-2.7, bytecode

I would like to avoid cluttering up my working directory with Python bytecode `*.pyc` files. Python 3.2+ [uses a subdirectory](https://docs.python.org/dev/whatsnew/3.2.html#pep-3147-pyc-repository-directories) called `__pycache__` for this purpose.

Since many of the projects I work on are Python 2.7, I'm wondering if there are any workarounds or utilities that can allow me to implement some similar behavior in my case?

Comment: Use an editor, that hides *.pyc files or include build-step before testing your programs.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the `-B` option of Python:

```
-B     : don't write .py[co] files on import; also PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE=x
```

So, you can run `python -B test.py` or set `PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE` appropriately.

Comment: "appropriately" is misleading here: `PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE` can be set to anything, python interpreter does not care, as long as the variable exists, the important thing is that it exists